# Panel not anchor to right

Tags: c#, frameworks, backend

I try the development front end of the application. But I have one problem, the panel is not anchored to right, ... this panel is dynamic but I don't understand, why not work.

[image]

[image]

```
            FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            flp.AutoScroll = true;
            flp.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            pnl.Controls.Add(flp);
            Panel pnl1 = new Panel();
            pnl1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
            pnl1.Size = new Size(flp.Width - 18, 40);
            pnl1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 209);
            pnl1.Margin = new Padding(8, 2, 0, 0);
            flp.Controls.Add(pnl1);
```

Can help me thanks.

Comment: To 'Anchor right' doen't mean it sits at the right border but that its distance from the right border will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the width of `FlowLayoutPanel`. I see you set the size of `Panel` base on the width of the flow layout

```
pnl1.Size = new Size(flp.Width - 18, 40);
```

---

**Update:**
After get more information from comment. This is behavior of `FlowLayoutPanel`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: About size of flowlayoutpanel i not set. Flowlayoutpanel is dock  fill

Comment: @ANDRECustódio: Yes, I try to create a project and reproduce your problems. I add another panel into the Flow layout (Top Down) and I resize the second panel, the size of anchor panel is scale. You can refer to this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Le_VU i found problem. I change flowlayoutpanel to panel1 and panel2 is worked (anchored to right). Thanks!!!